# How to open a partial view in asp.net mvc without using jquery or java script?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to open partial page as popup with out java script or jquery,when i search in the google i am getting only using javascript.

if user disable javascript also i would like to open view as pop up.

kindly show some sample on this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you search Google, you are only getting that answer because that is the only way to force a "popup".  Your only other option is to open the link in a new window/tab using the `target=_blank` attribute on the `<a>` tag.  People turning off JavaScript is not a thing to really worry about in 99.5% of a typical userbase.

Comment: Do you mean popup as in new window? Or some kind of lightbox effect? e.g. [a pure CSS pop up box](http://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO)